# "Class, interface, record, or enum expected" in front of package?

Tags: java, oop, constructor, package

This is a program answer provided by a professor, but it has an error in it that i'm currently unable to ask them about. Forgive me if the answer is obvious, i'm still a beginner! Thank you in advance to anyone who can help. I don't believe the error is cause by a missing bracket by the way, but maybe i'm wrong.

```
//This problem creates a car of a specified make and model.  The car
//accelerates 25 miles an hour and decelerates to 0 miles per hour
package module10assignment;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Module10Assignment {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Local variables
    String inputModel;
    String inputMake;
    Integer index;

    //Create a Car object
    Car Auto = new Car();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Get variables for a car
    System.out.println("Enter a model year:");
    inputModel = keyboard.nextLine();
    Auto.setModel(inputModel);
  `
    System.out.println("Enter make:");
    inputMake = keyboard.nextLine();
    Auto.setMake(inputMake);

    //Show variables for a car
    System.out.println("\nThe car year is " + Auto.getModel());
    System.out.println("\nThe car model is " + Auto.getMake() + "\n");

    System.out.println("I'm starting my car...");

    index = 1;

    //Show speed for each of 5 accelerations
    while (index <= 5){

        Auto.setAccelerate();
        index += 1;
    }

    System.out.println("The car speed after 5 accelerations is " +
            Auto.getSpeed()+ "\n");

    index = 1;

    //Show speed for each of 5 decelerations
    while (index <= 5){

        Auto.setBrake();
        index += 1;
    }

    System.out.println("The car speed after 5 breaks is " +
            Auto.getSpeed()+ "\n");




 }

}

***// THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR SHOWS UP!!!!!!*** 
package module10assignment;

public class Car {

private String make;
private String model;
private Integer speed = 0;

public void Car(String make, String model){

    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;

}

public void setMake(String make) {
    this.make = make;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public String getMake() {
    return make;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setAccelerate(){

    //Increase speed by 5 mph
    this.speed += 5;
    System.out.println("Accelerating to " + this.speed + " miles per hour.");
 }

public void setBrake(){

    //Decrease speed by 5 mph
    this.speed -= 5;
    System.out.println("Slowing to " + this.speed + " miles per hour.");
    }

   public Integer getSpeed(){
     return speed;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are `public class Car` and `public class Module10Assignment` in the same source code file? If so, that is a mistake. They need to be in separate source files, one named `Car.java` and the other named `Module10Assignment.java`.  (If they are not in the same source code file, please edit the question to show that.)

Answer (score 2):

In your model class code you made a mistake in constructor, Because constructor do not have any return type, and you assign the void to constructor.

```
public void Car(String make, String model){
   
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
}
```

Please remove the void from this constructor,
Your Code should be like this:

```
public Car(String make, String model){

    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
}
```